# Software design: recommend approach to avoid slicing/type erasure here

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Here is a concrete minimal example to formulate my question :

In small ball game, you have a physics engine that moves the objects regularly:

```
void move(set< PhysicalObject* > objets, Duration t)
```

And that engine can use user defined behaviour when a collision happens (using a strategy class). For instance, default strategy is to update objects directions, but you can provide it with a custom strategy class that kills objects according to some specific rules.

```
void update_after_collision(DerivedObject* a, DerivedObject* b)
```

In order to implement new behaviour during a collision, I have some specific derived classes (they have additional attributes/methods corresponding to their lifetime, etc.)

**The problem is: the engine calls the update_after_collision strategy, hence I can't use my derived class is this strategy without using a visitor pattern or a type cast. Note that the engine only knows about the base class, not the derived ones.**

Is there a way to avoid it? What is the standard approach to look at?

Is another programming paradigm better for this particular case?

EDIT : Code is written in C++

Comment: In my opinion, each of your objects should implement a HandleCollision method on an ICollidable interface that takes the same two arguments: *mass and velocity of the colliding object.*  There are a few reasons why I think this, but the primary reason is that *your update_after_collision method appears to know too much* about each object.  The object itself should decide whether it is dead after the collision, not some outside method.

Comment: You need to dispatch dynamically here, so a visitor or a type cast seems adequate. If you are asking for alternatives, all I can think of is the following (which could quickly become impractical): separate your instances into different buckets according to their type (at creation time) and change the `update_after_collision` callback (it is a callback, isn't it?) when computing the update function for each set of objects. Is there a reason you want to avoid having a visitor?

Comment: @RobertHarvey : (1) if the physic engine can't know about "object dying" so I still would have to do a cast somewhere. Do you see a workaround ?

Comment: @coredump : visitor patters annoy me because they prevent the addition of new derived class. When I have to use one, I often think that a functionnal style would be better than object oriented.
The buckets idea is interesting ! Here I can't because I have to handle different types at once, e.g. collide(D1, D2) ; collide(D2, D2) ; etc.
Yes it is a callback class (I just wrote the method, but it's the same)

Comment: @Julien__: A dead object should still be able to communicate its dead state to the physics engine in some generic way; i.e. `IKillable`.

Comment: Is is true that you have to handle two different types at once?  Which is to say you can't call `a.update_after_collision(b); /*and*/ b.update_after_collision(a /*or some clone of the original a*/);`?  The simpler dispatch should fit OOP better. Just checking...

Comment: @ErikEidt I could do that, but it would "glue" my derived class together, and I would like to avoid that. For instance, D1 should not know about D2. And I should be able to add D3 afterward without recompiling D1.

Comment: You're saying you can't find an appropriate base class or interface for the parameter in `a.update_after_collision(b);`, because `a` will have to know about different kinds of `b`s.  I see, oh, well, had to ask...

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is a typical use-case of runtime multiple-dispatch, and depending on the actual object-oriented language you intend to use, this is either built-in or requires some work.
I am sorry this answer cannot be more precise, but this depends largely on the actual programming language.

Assuming a Java-esque language, you could quickly devise a custom dispatch method: a simple organisation of "classes" in an enumerated type can be enough at first and quite easy to modify. Each object holds a type tag indicating which types it belongs to.

Your collision method can hold a square matrix of specialized callbacks for each combination of types. In pseudo-code:

```
collisions[from.tag][to.tag]
```

... refers to the method you need to call with the given `from` and `to` objects.
You can extend your set of tags, but this requires a recompilation phase. But binding tags to effective methods can be done at runtime while debugging, if you want.

If you want to introduce inheritance, this becomes a little more involved: imagine there is no specific method for a tag `T` (an empty cell in the `collisions` matrix), you should fall back to its parent type `P(T)` (assuming single-inheritance). For that you could have a `parent` member inside each of your enum value.

For C++, have a look at [Open Multi-Methods for C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/multimethods.pdf) from Stroustrup et al.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and for the link (+1). Still, I'm looking for something different : extracting subclasses, using composition, etc. in order to avoid such an approach.
If multiple dispatch / multimethods in C++ interest you, and if implementing a visitor pattern doesn't bother you, have a look at that library (it's in french, but code should be sefl explanatory) : https://bitbucket.org/Gauss_/library-multiple-dispatch-in-cpp/src/56b0aa08e19bdbb56d4bebceb0d5588f4b853a92/Multiple%20Dispatch%20Release/exemple_simple.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default